# batch tslint on several lines

Tags: batch-processing, jslint, tslint

I  launch a batch that contains a tslint command

```
tslint -c ../tslint.json --project tsconfig.json --out output.txt --format msbuild -e '**/bin/Debug/**' -e '**/fonts/**' -e '**/images/**' -e '**/Scripts/**' -e '**/typings/**' -e 'file1.ts' -e 'file2.ts' -e 'file3.ts' -e 'file3.ts' -e 'file4.ts'  
…
```

unfortunately I want to exclude a lot of files and it is not easy to read so I would like to read the same file but with the possibility of being able to go to the line and write Something on that form:

```
    tslint -c ../tslint.json --project tsconfig.json --out output.txt --format msbuild 
-e '**/bin/Debug/**' 
-e '**/fonts/**' 
-e '**/images/**' 
-e '**/Scripts/**' 
-e '**/typings/**' 
-e 'file1.ts' 
-e 'file2.ts' 
-e 'file3.ts' 
-e 'file3.ts' 
-e 'file4.ts'
```

Do you know how to do this please?

Comment: You may be able to use a caret to escape the line returns, i.e. **`1.`** `tslint -c ../tslint.json --project tsconfig.json --out output.txt --format msbuild ^`, **`2.`** `-e '**/bin/Debug/**' ^` **`3.`** `-e '**/fonts/**' ^` etc.

Comment: @Compo yes you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my comment as an answer.

You could try escaping the line returns with carets, **`^`**, including a space before each:

```bat
tslint --config ../tslint.json --project tsconfig.json --out output.txt --format msbuild ^
--exclude '**/bin/Debug/**' ^
--exclude '**/fonts/**' ^
--exclude '**/images/**' ^
--exclude '**/Scripts/**' ^
--exclude '**/typings/**' ^
--exclude 'file1.ts' ^ 
--exclude 'file2.ts' ^
--exclude 'file3.ts' ^
--exclude 'file4.ts'
```

Alternatively, start the individual lines with a space and finish each proceeding line with the caret, **`^`**:

```bat
tslint -c ../tslint.json -p tsconfig.json -o output.txt -f msbuild^
 -e '**/bin/Debug/**'^
 -e '**/fonts/**'^
 -e '**/images/**'^
 -e '**/Scripts/**'^
 -e '**/typings/**'^
 -e 'file1.ts'^
 -e 'file2.ts'^
 -e 'file3.ts'^
 -e 'file3.ts'^
 -e 'file4.ts'
```

As it is unlikely that multiple spaces will be problematic to `tslint`, you could even try this:

```bat
tslint -c ../tslint.json^
       -p tsconfig.json^
       -o output.txt^
       -f msbuild^
       -e '**/bin/Debug/**'^
       -e '**/fonts/**'^
       -e '**/images/**'^
       -e '**/Scripts/**'^
       -e '**/typings/**'^
       -e 'file1.ts'^
       -e 'file2.ts'^
       -e 'file3.ts'^
       -e 'file4.ts'
```